# PostgreSQL - Writing aggregate function which do average or percentile

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create aggregate function

`avg_or_percentile(column, type::text)`

which aggregate by average or given percentile depending on parameter 'type' which can take values like:

'avg', '50', '99' etc.

If 'avg' - aggregate using 'avg' function, if other - use percentile.

I don't see any possibility to include default avg function or aggregate function in my custom one.

If i try doing something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avg_or_percentile_transition(state internal, value double precision)
RETURNS internal AS $$
BEGIN
    CASE agg_type
        WHEN 'avg' THEN
            return int8_avg_accum(state, value);
        ELSE
            return ordered_set_transition(state, value);
    END CASE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am getting error, that internal type cannot be used.

Is the only way to achieve this to decompose them and combine both implementations in a custom one?

Am I missing something?

EDIT 1:

Right now I am achieving it using query like this ($ are macros from grafana):

```
Select 
  $__timeGroup("Closed", $__interval, 0) as "time",
  CASE
    WHEN '${Func}'='avg' 
    THEN avg(duration)
    ELSE percentile_cont(try_cast_numeric('0.${Func}')) within group (order by duration asc)
  END as "${Func}"
from
  (SELECT
    *,
    extract(epoch from "Closed"-"Created")/3600 as duration
  FROM pr."PullRequests" pr
  WHERE $__timeFilter("Closed") and (pr."TeamName" = ${Team} or ${Team} = 'All')) withDuration
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time
```

But it is very ugly statement and it gets even worse, when we add additional columns to aggregate. Would love to simplify it.

Comment: Is `type` a parameter of the query, or really a column (i.e. different for each aggregated row)?

Comment: [Pseudo types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html): *The internal pseudo-type is used to declare functions that are meant only to be called internally by the database system, and not by direct invocation in an SQL query. If a function has at least one internal-type argument then it cannot be called from SQL*

Comment: parameter of a query, it will be called like this

select 
   avg_or_percentile(duration, 'avg')
from table

Comment: Right now, i have to do something like this:

${Func} - is macro of my tool. 

Select 
  CASE
    WHEN '${Func}'='avg' 
    THEN avg(duration)
    ELSE percentile_cont(try_cast_numeric('0.${Func}')) within group (order by duration asc)
  END as "${Func}"
from
  (SELECT
    *,
    extract(epoch from "Closed"-"Created")/3600 as duration
  FROM pr.Table)) withDuration

Comment: I wanted to simplify it :)

Comment: Then really you should just write `CASE type WHEN 'avg' THEN avg(duration) ELSE percentile(duration) END` in your query - oh wait I see that's where you're coming from

Comment: See my comment above, it's a hell of a additional lines to achieve this